# Mono.Cecil - How to know a method has variable-arguments?

Tags: c#, cil, mono.cecil

In C# we have `__arglist` keyword which makes method variable-argument like this:

```
public static void PrintFormat(string format, __arglist) 
{
    ....
}
```

It compiles to :

```
.method public hidebysig static vararg void PrintFormat ( string format ) cil managed 
{
    ....
}
```

Note that `vararg`. So how can we know a method has variable-arguments in Mono.Cecil ?

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/search?q=vararg) allow you to answer the question yourself?

Comment: @JeroenMostert I'm lazy :D. Post an answer, please.

Comment: I was this close to doing that, but then I decided to teach you to fish. I don't even use Mono.Cecil, it feels increasingly bad to take credit for answers on it! :-P

Answer (score 0):

[@JeroenMostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) pointed that out. [Source](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/blob/eea822cad4b6f320c9e1da642fcbc0c129b00a6e/Mono.Cecil/MethodReference.cs#L184-L187).

```
public static bool IsVarArg (this IMethodSignature self)
{
    return (self.CallingConvention & MethodCallingConvention.VarArg) != 0;
}
```